# Passenger and Apache2 Display File Directory Structure rather than application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I setup rails app on passenger-3.0.9 and apache2. But when in execute rails through apache2 i.e http/localhost it shows the rails app file structure.and not run the app. My logs are

> [Sat Nov 12 21:20:36 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
>   Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3 with Suhosin-Patch
>   configured -- resuming normal operations

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName localhost 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name 
  <Directory /var/www/project_name> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews AllowOverride all Order allow,deny allow from all
  </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you provide your virtual host configuration?

Comment: yeah, my virtual host configuration is default configuration

Comment: Please update the issue with the configuration.  I'm not sure what your default configuration is.  The issue is likely due to not pointing the configuration to the proper public path.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> 
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name 
        <Directory /var/www/project_name> 
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
                AllowOverride all 
                Order allow,deny 
                allow from all 
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 2):

Set your DocumentRoot to your public folder so:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name/public
```

In production if you deploy with capistrano this would likely become

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/project_name/current/public
```

You also need to update your Directory setting to the public folder as well.

If your virtual host isn't pointing to your public folder Apache doesn't know where to serve your applications assets from properly.

Comment: I want to know. How to run other project i.e phpmyadmin,php,ror  projects on this Virtualhost

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to setup php projects with passenger so you will need to find answers for that in another question.  As for other RoR projects with passenger you can define multiple virtual host configurations for each app.  If you develop on a mac I would recommend passenger pane to quickly setup configurations http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane otherwise you can do it manually be setting each virtual hosts servername and document roots to the proper domains and public folders of each app.  If you run into trouble setting that up starting a new question should help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `PassengerAppRoot` attribute?

`DocumentRoot` points toward the static part of the app while `PassengerAppRoot` is used to point towards the rails application

[Here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger)'s an article about it