# Ruby/Rails Apache2 & Passenger setup returning directory listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, ubuntu-12.04, vps

It's worth nothing, first of all, that I've got a fully-functional Apache2 server (on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS) with multiple working virtual hosts (but this is my first attempt to deploy a Rails site). Additionally, the Rails site I'm trying to launch is fully functional on my local WEBRick server.

I've referenced various online instructions for making Apache, Ruby, Rails & Passenger play nice together, including:

- [This from Linode, my host](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid) (they don't offer documentation specific for 12.04)
- [This from O'Reilly](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/production_id35801033.html)
- The Passenger documentation that's part of the installation process of `passenger-install-apache2-module`
- The [online Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3)
- Various old SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154959/apache-rails-passenger-displaying-site-index) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105592/passenger-and-apache2-display-file-directory-structure-rather-than-application)

To summarize, so far I've:

1. Installed Ruby (`ruby -v` in site root returns 1.9.3), RVM, Ruby Gems, Rails (`rails -v` in app folder returns 3.2.8 and I can start a `rails server` in the app folder) & Passenger (including all dependencies)
2. As instructed by `passenger-install-apache2-module`, I've added the following lines to the bottom of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

   ```
   LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger 3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
   ```
3. Created & enabled (it's listed in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`) a virtual host `/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo.com` that contains the following:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName foo.com
     DocumentRoot /home/user/public/foo.com/public
     <Directory /home/user/public/foo.com/public>
       AllowOverride all
       Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Uploaded my Rails app to `/home/user/public/foo.com/`
5. Did a `bundle install` in `/home/user/public/foo.com/`
6. On my local OSX machine, I've add `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx foo.com` [the VPS IP] to `/etc/hosts`.
7. Restarted Apache

But when I navigate to foo.com in the browser, I simply see a listing of `/home/user/public/foo.com/public`. Also, there are no recent entries in the Apache `error.log`. However, whenever I `restart` Apache I get:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Fri Oct 26 00:04:12 2012] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting [Fri Oct 26 00:04:13 2012] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
   ...done.
```

I'm hoping I've overlooked something really stupid. Any help figure out what that is would be much, much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working with apache2.2, you should not include the following in apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger 3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Instead you should create 2 files on `/etc/apache2/mods-available`:

**passenger.load** with:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

**passenger.conf** with:

```
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Finally you just run:

```
a2enmod passenger
```

And it's done. By the way, when you make it work you might consider using a more recent version of ruby (1.9.3... or so). The best way to do that is using [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm no longer seeing the directory listing at the page (so I've accepted your answer) but, instead, I'm seeing a Passenger error page. Arg.

Comment: "no such file to load -- bundler/setup" and just a few minutes ago I created a question with all the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092293/no-such-file-to-load-bundler-setup-on-apache-passenger-server

Comment: it may also be worth nothing that all I apparently needed to do was remove those 3 lines from apache2.conf. Passenger had already been enabled. **passenger.load** already existed and contains the following (I made no changes): `LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so`. **passenger.conf** also existed and contains the following (again, I made no changes): `<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>`

Comment: Thank you mate it has given me a new birth.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to use passenger to run a Rails 2.3. app I had created a couple of years ago and needed to move to a new server.

I added passenger, but all I got was a directory listing.

In the end it turned out that I did not have a `config.ru` file.
It was enough to create a file with those two lines:

`require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new`

It took me about 5 hours to find out I was missing those two lines. I am wishing everybody in a similar situation that he/she will find this answer before spending too much time on this... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, turned out, that in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passanger.load I had the apache2 installed passenger.so that didn't want to work, changed it to the gems installed passenger.so

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```